# I can't put this query to work... 'mysql' 'phpmyadmin'

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I give up, I've rewrote the code 3 times and I can't find the problem in the code... I've done much complex databases but I can't find what is wrong in this little thing... here's the code and the error in the end.

Thank you :)

```
create database whatgameshouldiplay;

use whatgameshouldiplay;

CREATE TABLE `randomgame` (
`nomejogo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`nomejogo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table `estilos` (
`codestilo` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`estilo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`codestilo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Create table `gameEstilos`(
    `nomejogo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `estilo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    primary key(`nomejogo`,`estilo`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`nomejogo`) REFERENCES `randomgame` ( `nomejogo` ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ( `estilo` ) REFERENCES `estilos` ( `estilo` ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Error
SQL query:

Create table `gameEstilos`(
        `nomejogo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        `estilo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        primary key(`nomejogo`,`estilo`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`nomejogo`) REFERENCES `randomgame` ( `nomejogo` ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY ( `estilo` ) REFERENCES `estilos` ( `estilo` ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
MySQL said: Documentation

'#'1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FOREIGN KEY in a table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

Below SQL are working after changing PRIMARY KEY from codestilo to estilo and also removed AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
CREATE TABLE `randomgame` (
`nomejogo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`nomejogo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table `estilos` (
`codestilo` int(100) NOT NULL ,
`estilo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`estilo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Create table `gameEstilos`(
    `nomejogo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `estilo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    primary key(`nomejogo`,`estilo`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`nomejogo`) REFERENCES `randomgame` ( `nomejogo` ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ( `estilo` ) REFERENCES `estilos` ( `estilo` ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: But i need codestilo to be auto_increment, what if i use it as foreign key as primary in estilos?

Comment: Well i was really sleepy yesterday, thank you for your help I've managed to get what i Wanted :)